# How to get all points within a box?

Tags: java, bounding-boxes

What is the fastest way to get all of the points within a bounding box? If I had an `ArrayList<Point>`, and they weren't mapped to coordinates, would I have to loop through every point to see if it is in those bounds? Is there a faster way?

Comment: You want to detect a collision between two objects ? can you be more specific ?

Comment: @Ion Farima I though i was specific but i want to get all of the points in that arraylist which are in a specific rectangle or box.

Comment: Sorry for my negligence, but you want to detect if a body collides with another object ? If yes, you could simply use the x, y coords. of the 2 bodies

Comment: @user3466304 is it an axially aligned box or not?

Comment: @concept3d yes its pretty simpple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on two things.

One - Is your box axially aligned? (ie. Is there a face pointing up, down, left, right, forward and back, or is it rotated ?)

Two - Are your points at all sorted?

If you are using an axially aligned box, you can skip this first step. Work out a Quaternion which defines the rotation of the box. From now on, when I refer to a point, I am talking about the point after being rotated by this Quaternion. If you have any difficulties with this step, google it, Quaternions are a big topic which I'd rather not go into unless you need more info.

Next it's pretty straight forward. Loop through the items and work out if their x is more than the box.minX and less than box.maxX (as with Y and Z). If this is true, then it is within the box.

There are a few ways you could speed these up, if your points are sorted in such a way that allows you to conclude at some point, that no more of them will be within the box, you can skip out. For example, if the box is at the origin (0, 0, 0) and your points are sorted in distance from the origin, it will reach a stage where you can conclude that all points left in the list are too far to even both doing checks, and therefore can break out of the loop.

Really there's no extremely fast ways of solving this problem when the points are stored in simply a List.

**TLDR;** minx <= x <= maxX && miny <= y <= maxY && minz <= z <= maxZ. 
Google Matricies and Quaternions, possibly Octrees too.

Comment: Good answer. +1 You forgot about using OpenCV or another computation shader.

Comment: Thanks i never thought about ordering them but good idea

Answer (score 0):

I read the answer by @Randomman159 and am not going to repeat what is written there.

Two important tools for processing a large quantities of data in parallel are SIMD and the computation shader. These allow you to perform a lot of computation in parallel. Another tool used to improve performance with tasks that can be parallelized is multithreaded programming. You need to try them out and check the results before making a choice. Sometimes (for instance) writing to the graphics card memory is more time consuming than the benefit from using a computation shader.

Comment: Not only memory transfer time, the algorithm perform so little actual arithmetic, it spends far more time reading and writing memory (loads and stores) which makes parallelization even less useful.

Comment: I think you may be referring to a 2d axis aligned bounding box.

Generally, if we are talking about random points in a none-axis-aligned box (that isn't 2d), I find that a computation shader could greatly improve performance from my experience. This may or may not be the case with Java but it has been the case in some tests I've ran in other languages.

Comment: yes I was referring to an AABB in case of 2D/3D, the algorithm in that case is so simple that will hardly benefit from any computational power given by parallalization, almost all of its time will be spent reading and writing data.

Comment: I would rather not depend on the graphics card, but thanks!

Comment: @user3466304 - It is not merely depending on the graphics card. There are simply other (none-serial) ways to increase performance by using SIMD (single instruction, multiple data) or multithreading (or both). It is the correct way to process large quantities of data efficiently (gpu or cpu is not the point). The idea is that there are oft neglected ways to boost performance when it comes to processing large quantities of data. I thought this was the heart of your question.